# Tree Map in high charts fourth level is not working

Tags: jquery, highcharts

In Highcharts- tree map, 3 levels are given. Regions - country- disease., Now I need fourth level for it. I tried reducing the level to two, it worked but it doesn't work for fourth level. Please tell me where I went wrong. Here is the fiddle

Original Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/euaohp77/

```
 var data = {
        'South-East Asia': {
            'Sri Lanka': {
            'aaa1':{
            'xyz1':'89.2',
            'xyz2':'98.5'
            },
            'aaa2':{

            'xyz1':'89.2',
            'xyz2':'98.5'

            }
            },
            'Bangladesh':{
            'bbb1':{
             'xyz1':'38.2',
            'xyz2':'67.5'
            },
            'bbb2':{
             'xyz1':'92.2',
            'xyz2':'95.5'
            }
            }
        }

    },
```

Modified Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nr3Lzqr0/2/ (increased another level [Not Working])

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the relation between points by id and parentID. Levels are not limited.

```
data: [{
    id: 'id_0',
    name: 'test0',
    value: 20
  },{
    color: 'red',
    id: 'id_1',
    name: 'test1',
    parent: 'id_0',
    value: 10
  },{
    color: 'green',
    id: 'id_2',
    name: 'test2',
    parent: 'id_1',
    value: 15
  },{
    color: 'orange',
    id: 'id_3"',
    name: 'test3',
    parent: 'id_2',
    value: 20
  }]
}],
```

Simple demo:

- http://jsfiddle.net/coyye21t/